# Strange behaviour with Navigate().back()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm facing an issue about the back function in selenium.
When I call it, it does nothing but if I call it twice, it works perfectly.
I've tried manually on my web browser and one back button is enought to go back.

Someone know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you giving it time to work?

Comment: The language Java has nothing to do with Javasctipt

Comment: Yes I'm giving it time to work but nothing happen

Comment: You don't say what browser you're using, but have a read of this: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8741/11509

Answer (score 0):

The behavior might be a result of a scripted page with some code for auto-refreshing, suppressing or overriding the back button event /action.

So you might:

- **debug** the page and stop on any JavaScript execution

  - and ask for a correction/change if you are in control of the page
- **avoid** the back-button-action from Selenium-framework, that simulates browser back navigation

  - use instead a given button (if available)
- **implement** this "feature" in your own framework as a workaround to click it (always) twice to ensure successful back-navigation